# Ubuntu won't recognize my earbuds when connected to my monitor

Tags: headphones

I have a monitor which has a built in headphone jack so I can connect my earbuds there, in windows, the jack works perfectly but in ubuntu, it doesn't recognize them. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  This is only a guess, but have you tried `pavucontrol` (pulse audio volume control) and selecting the desired "Output device"

Comment: That's strange. Why should Ubuntu or Windows recognition earbuds connected to another device? In a setup like this, they should see the output sound channel to the monitor,  but should not care about what's connected to the monitor's output. I also have monitor with a 3.5mm headphone jack for output, and HDMI video/audio for input. Headphones or speakers can be connected, Ubuntu doesn't care.